# create new instance from existing instance

Tags: java

For some reason when I create a new instance of an object from an existing instance and change values in the new instance, it also changes the values in the existing instance. I would prefer if it only changed the state of the values in the new instance though. I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
Foo existing = new Foo(1, "foo");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   Foo newFoo = existing;
   System.out.println(newFoo.getName()); //Prints "foo" as expected
   newFoo.setName("bar");
   System.out.println(existing.getName()); //This prints out "bar"?
}
```

Neither of the objects are static.

Comment: This -> `Foo newFoo = existing;` doesn't create a new instance of `Foo`. Just a new reference to the same instance.

Comment: If I was you I'd be looking at the clone() method, seen as you don't want to manipulate the first object, rather a clone of it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a new instance at Runtime with:

```
Foo newFoo = existing.getClass().newInstance();
```

Note that the newly created instance **will not be** a copy of the `existing` one.

However, if you *do need* to a have a copy of the `existing` object, you can play a bit with the `Clonable` interface.

First, you have to make the `Foo` class implement the `Cloneable` interface:

```
public class Foo implements Cloneable { ... }
```

Then, you need to provide an implementation of the `clone()` method that will return a copy of you object:

```
public Foo clone() {
    return new Foo(this.id, this.name); //for example
}
```

And finally, you can invoke the newly introduced `clone()` method like this:

```
Foo newFoo = existing.clone();
```

This will give you a fresh `Foo` object, but with a copied properties from the `existing` one.

Comment: I need it to be a copy though. It should first print out `existing.getName()` then  change it afterwards.

Comment: Why using reflection? `new Foo ()` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you do

```
Foo newFoo = existing;
```

You are not creating a new instance. Instead, you are simply pointing the `newFoo` variable to the same object `existing` points to.

What you're doing is basically this:

```
Foo existing = new Foo(1, "foo")       <=> existing -> Foo(1, "foo")
Foo newFoo = existing                  <=> existing -> Foo(1, "foo") <- newFoo
newFoo.setName("bar")                  <=> existing -> Foo(1, "bar") <- newFoo
System.out.println(existing.getName()) <=> System.out.println(Foo(1, "bar").getName())
```

If you want to create a new instance you can do:

```
Foo newFoo = new Foo(existing.getId(), existing.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new reference, not a new instance. Try something like this...

```
Foo newFoo = oldFoo.clone()
```

This preserves the original objects' values

Answer (score 0):

To create a copy of your `Foo` instance you could inherit from `Cloneable` and implement a `clone()` method as follows:

```
class Foo implements Cloneable {
  @Override
  public Foo clone() {
    try {
      return (Foo)super.clone();
    }
    catch(CloneNotSupportedException e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
  }
}
```

(see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html as well)

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy constructor:

```
public Foo (Foo another) {
    this.propertyA = another.propertyA;
    // etc.
}
```

Then, inside the `for` loop:

```
Foo existing = new Foo(1, "foo");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Foo newFoo = new Foo(existing);
    // system out etc
}
```

This is the best way to copy instances of a class.

Answer (score 0):

You are **not** creating a new instance, you are just creating a new variable which points to the same instance.You either have to create a copy constructor or create a new instance with values of the existing instance as shown below :

```
Foo instance = new Foo(existing.getPropertyA(), existing.getPropertyB());
```

Answer (score -1):

In the line

```
Foo newFoo = existing;
```

You are not creating a new instance of Foo; you are copying the reference of `existing` into the variable `newFoo` any actions taken on either `existing` or `newFoo` will affect the same underlying object

There is a very thorough discussion on how to copy an object in java here: [How do I copy an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java)